# SQL Server- how to import .000 files

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to import into an sql server data base, data from a strange file with a weird data format (.000).

I tried doing this just to see the data:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'f:\WINREST_TESTE\fdocheader.000',
  FORMATFILE='f:\WINREST_TESTE\fdocheader.000'     
  ) as t1 ;
```

And I got the following error: XML parsing: line 2, character 0, incorrect document syntax

Can you help me doing doing this?

Note: I'm using SQL server 2016 and the file format cannot be changed due to business necessities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the `.000` file look like?

Comment: I assume it is similar to .b1 files, did u tried import export wizard by renaming that file as csv for testing

Comment: Have you asked the provider of these files for documentation of the format, or to verify that they're producing valid files? The error reads like it's either malformed XML, or non-XML data that's being treated as XML. Without seeing a sample of the file, it's difficult to say which.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Inside the file are many rows like this: 
25       96 7044222711/09/201710:17 0     1 4     0 3         9.00Pag. mesa 1     
That I will use to load a table I already have in my database.

Comment: Is this meant to be a plain text file that can be read, or is it a binary/encoded format?

Comment: Why are you using the data file as the format file?

Comment: @alroc The files are valid. But they are converted to .000 extension on purpose. If I edit them with notedpad I can see the information in there.

Comment: @alroc yes, It is a plain text file

Comment: To explain a little further, the FORMATFILE parameter should point to a file that has the instructions for the bulk insert to parse the file.  The fact that it's basically malformed or missing is what your error message indicates (since the new default for a formatting file is XML).  If you're loading a text file, remove the FORMATFILE option and use the delimiters (FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql

Comment: @MiguelCunha could you provide some sample data please? A screenshot of the file opened in Editor or something? .000 can be anything - from a backup file over a part-archive to anything else... if you could provide sample data and if possible the beginning of the file, we can try to help.

Comment: @Tyron78 https://ufile.io/5c2f1 Here you have the file I want to import.
Do you need the "FormatFile" ?(if I really need one)

Comment: @Tyron78 And this is the original one, in the .000 format file https://ufile.io/m7yns
The first one I sent I already converted to txt just to simplify, but It would be awesome If I could import the original one withou changing the format

Comment: @MiguelCunha please put an excerp of the file here as code or whatever. Can't download and open foreign files right now.

Comment: @Tyron78 As an example, This is a line of the file:
25       96 7044222711/09/201710:17 0     1 4     0 3         9.00Pag. mesa 1

Comment: @MiguelCunha OK and could you paste your format file here as well please? Shouldn't be too long judging by the length of the example provided by you,

Comment: @Tyron78 Thank you for your help, but I already made it. I userd bulk insert function and converted the EOL file format to Windows (It was in unix format).

Once again, thanks :)